# Proper port forwarding under Ubuntu

Tags: networking, bittorrent, transmission, port-forwarding

What is the correct way to open ports in Ubuntu and use [Transmission](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo) in active mode?

I opened port in my Technicolor 7200 router using [this guide](https://portforward.com/technicolor/tc7200/) as follows:

[image]

Then, I opened a port via terminal:

```
sudo ufw allow 6881
```

But, when I check if port is open using [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) service, it says:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Also, how to do port forwarding if my external IP is dynamic? I am trying to open some ports to get Transmission working in active mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are normally two steps in configuring port forwarding.  Additional to what you have already done, the next step may be to add a firewall rule on your border router to permit the incoming traffic you are forwarding.  Some systems do this automatically however that would be the first place I would look. The firewall rule should allow the destination port(s) you specified to hit the outside (internet) side interface.

Comment: @ValerySaharov You do have restrictions by default as only the typical ports are open in home routers. UPnP may enable opening other ports on demand but sometimes, as indicated in the answer, you need to also set the port forwarding at the router.